# Merge pdf by file name using Mac automator

Tags: macos, pdf, merge, applescript, automator

I am trying to get automator to merge PDF pages from two files with similar names.

Right now I already have a service workflow in automator that is able to merge two selected files:

[image]

While this workflow is certainly useful, I still have to manually select the files to be merged one by one. Also, the resulting file name is being renamed with an apparently random string of letters after the set words.

I will mainly use this script for getting numbered files (ex: 10989.pdf) merged with files containing those numbers, with names like "lst0090**10989**.pdf". Those files are all in a folder with various other files with names following the same system, so what I need is for the workflow to get the numbered files and join them to their respective lst file, copy it to another folder while maintaining the numbered file name (in this case, 10989) and then doing the same for the other files in the folder.

How am I able to do this?

Additional information:
The first page of the merged file should always be the one of the numbered file (10989 in the exemple). The second one should be the one of the LST file. The resulting file should be named NF_LST xxxxx.pdf (xxxx being the name of the numbered file, 10989 in this case).

The lst filename always starts with lst and has 14 characters, the last of them always being the same as the numbered file name. The numbered filename changes from 3 characters to 6.

The following image shows what a typical folder contains:

[image: folder contents]

Comment: You've left out some very important information! **1.** When combining pages which file's pages are first and which file's pages are second in the combined document? **2.** Which filename is to be used when renaming, will it be e.g. **FN_LST 10989.pdf** or **FN_LST lst009010989.pdf** **3.** Are the number of digits always 9 with **lst….pdf** files and 5 with the corresponding numeric filename files? **4.** Do the non-numeric filenames all start with **lst**? Frankly, you should include an appropriate partial directory listing so we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: **5.** Are there files other then the ones to combine in the same directory, or just corresponding files to be combined?

Comment: Sorry for that, I will update de question. So, the first page should be the one of file 10989.pdf, and the second should be the one of the lst file.

The edited filename should be FN_LST 10989.pdf.

All the non numeric filenames start with LST. The numbers following LST may change but the last numbers are always the same as the numbered file name (in this case, 10989).

Comment: The LST filenames are always 14 characters, but the numbered files vary from 3 characters to 6. I added a print screen of a folder containing the files. Thanks in advance for you patience! @user3439894

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? E.g. macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has been tested under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.4 and 10.15.5 and it did not work for me under 10.15.5 as a *Quick Action*. It appears there is a *bug* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* when using the `find` *command* as formed. It also works under **macOS High Sierra**, and also as **shell script** in the three test environments. This further bolsters the *bug* assumption in 10.15.5.

This requires the use of `cpdf` from the third-party, free, [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](https://community.coherentpdf.com) -- Direct download link: [Download pre-built cpdf tool](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries/archive/master.zip)

[image: Combine PDF File Sets Automator Quick Action]

*Example* **bash script** *code*:

```bash
for i in "$@"; do
    [[ ${i} =~ .*/[0-9]{3,6}.*\.[pP][dD][fF] ]] || continue
    j="$(find "${i%/*}" -type f -iname "lst*${i##*/}")"
    [[ ${j} =~ .*/lst.*[0-9]{3,6}\.[pP][dD][fF] ]] || continue
    l=${j##*/}
    [[ ${#l} -eq 18  ]] || continue
    /usr/local/bin/cpdf -merge "${i}" "${j}" -o "${i%/*}/FN_LST ${i##*/}"
done
```

---

**As coded, it performs the following:**

- Checks the *files* passed are a 3 to 6 digit numeric named **PDF** *file*.
- Finds the corresponding **PDF** *file*, in the same *folder*, starting with **lst** and ending with the same 3 to 6 digit numeric named **PDF** *file*.
- If a corresponding **PDF** *file* is not found it moves to the next *file*.
- Validates the length of the found corresponding **PDF** *file* to be 18 characters, including the extension.
- Combines the matching sets with the 3 to 6 digit numeric named **PDF** *file* first in the new combined *file*.
- Creates the combined *file* as e.g. **FN_LST [0-9]{3,6}.pdf**, (FN_LST 10989.pdf), in the same *folder*, which can be changed.
- Does not overwrite an existing *file*.

---

To change the location of where the new combined *files* are created, in the e.g. `/usr/local/bin/cpdf ...` line, change `${i%/*}` in:

```bash
-o "${i%/*}/FN_LST ${i##*/}"
```

To:

```bash
-o "/path/to/FN_LST ${i##*/}"
```

Where `/path/to` is the *fully qualified directory pathname*, e.g.:

```bash
-o "$HOME/Documents/Combined PDF Files/FN_LST ${i##*/}"
```

---

**Note:** The `/path/to` *directory* must already exist as there is no *error handling* for it, although that too can be added, e.g.:

```bash
d="HOME/Documents/Combined PDF Files"
[[ -d ${d} ]] || mkdir -p "${d}"

for i in "$@"; do
    [[ ${i} =~ .*/[0-9]{3,6}.*\.[pP][dD][fF] ]] || continue
    j="$(find "${i%/*}" -type f -iname "lst*${i##*/}")"
    [[ ${j} =~ .*/lst.*[0-9]{3,6}\.[pP][dD][fF] ]] || continue
    l=${j##*/}
    [[ ${#l} -eq 18  ]] || continue
    /usr/local/bin/cpdf -merge "${i}" "${j}" -o "${d}/FN_LST ${i##*/}"
done
```

Comment: By the way... I was reading the GitHub of this tool and apparently, Apple is discontinuing use of non notarised executables. Couldn't this be the reason for the bug?